# How to extract avoiding special characters using regular expression extractor in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to extract **XYZ** from the below :

checkboxes__input' id='XYZ_2020-04-20' name='payment[invoices][XYZ][]' type='checkbox' value='2020-04-20'

using regular expression:

name='payment[invoices][(.*?)][]' type=

but it does not work. Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

As per [JMeter Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) guide `[` and `]` are [meta characters](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars) which stand for [character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) therefore they need to be escaped with a backslash like:

```
name='payment\[invoices\]\[(.*?)\]\[\]' type=
```

Demo:

[image]

---

If you're not too comfortable with regular expressions you can consider switching to the [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter) where you can just provide left and right boundaries and it will extract everything between them:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, Dmitri. Both worked. One more question to this:  I get several lines with different values like the above line from my HTTP request. I need to extract  
first 10 of theses values (ie. XYZ_2020-04-20), split each of them into 2 different values like XYZ and 2020-04-20 (so total of 20 values) in my subsequent HTTP request. How can I do it?